# Is an administration facility a bounded context in its own right?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Say I have a DDD application with three bounded contexts i.e. Sales, Production and Marketing.

Say I wanted to setup an administration facility.  The admin facility would allow superusers' to change data in the tables that are used by: SalesRepository; ProductionRepository and MarketingRepository.

How would the Administration facility pull information from the database:

Option 1) It use the three repositories i.e. SalesRepository; ProductionRepository and MarketingRepository

Option 2) Administration would be treated as a bounded context in its own right and have its own repository.  This could be a generic repository as the bounded context contains CRUD operations only i.e. there is no domain logic.

I am specifically asking if a simple Admin facility should be treated as a bounded context.  I am not asking: "what is a bounded context?".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What, in reference to DDD, is a bounded context?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237513/what-in-reference-to-ddd-is-a-bounded-context)

Comment: @Robert Harvey, thanks for the link.  However, I have already read it.  I understand what a bounded context is generally.  I am asking if a simple Administration facility (CRUD only) should be treated as a bounded context in its own right.

Comment: A bounded context corresponds to a business domain.  Is the Administration facility you speak of a business domain?  Note that DDD is primarily a *design philosophy,* not a coding methodology.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, business users from each bounded context (domain) will use the admin facility.  I am trying to figure out if the admin facility should have its own repository.  Is Administration an aggregate root?

Comment: Is it a business domain, in the same manner that the other business domains are identified?  I would suggest that it is.  If not a business domain, at least a defined process.  It's not necessarily just CRUD; you could have methods like `GrantAccess()`.

Comment: No, it is part of each business domain i.e. an admin function is required in the sales domain; also in the Production domain; also in the marketing domain etc.

Comment: Well, maybe it's not a bounded context, then.  You're still going to need its functionality, though.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, yes I agree.  Would it have its own repository or would it use the repositories of the other bounded contexts for its basic CRUD operations?

Comment: Which approach best meets your specific requirements?  Personally, I wouldn't take dependencies to all those other repositories if a single repository would do.

Comment: I would prefer to use a generic repository for the admin facility.  I just want to make sure that this is not a code smell.

Comment: What is a code smell? If it satisfies your specific requirements, what does the odor have to do with it?  The only criteria that are relevant to your application involve things like performance, maintainability, etc., not some vague notion of code smell.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: I know what it is.  I'm trying to figure out if *you* know what it is, in a way that is relevant to your specific project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64961/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-w0051977).

Comment: Would administrator's actions follow the same bounded context specific rules? I'm not refering to authorisation rules as the admin may do anything.

Comment: @Constantin Galbenu, administrators want to correct data quality mistakes.  They will also deal with queries from customers; suppliers etc.

Comment: But will they obey the same business rules? For example, you cannot buy an item if the inventory is empty. I try to understand if you need a different application or is the same with a *good* authorization bounded context.

Comment: @Constantin Galbenu, yes they will.

Comment: Then it is clear. I will give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood about your domain, you need to (create if it does not exist and) use an `authorization bounded context` (`AuthBC`) that will manage the access right to the other `BCs`.

If the `administrators` (users that have all the privileges/permissions in the system) need some new function that do not exist yet in the `BCs`, for example to `postpone` a `sale`, then that function will be added as usual but the access to it will be restricted to only the administrators (in fact you could restrict it to the users that have the privilege named `CAN_POSTPONE_A_SALE` but this depends on the internals of the `AuthBC`). This applies to the queries too, as they will be protected by the same `AuthBC`.

If you wonder how to integrate the `AuthBC` with the other `BCs`: you can do this in the `Application layer`, in the `Application services`; before executing the domain function, the service call an `application service` from the `AuthBC` and ask it if the current user can do some action identified for example by a string. Please note that this referencing to the `AuthBC` should not be done from an `aggregate` or in a `domain service`, only from an `application service`; in any domain layer you must have code that do checks specific to that domain only.

`BCs`=Bounded contexts

Comment: Thanks.  So it would have its own repository?

Comment: Of course. You persist the access rights of every user and/or resource.

Comment: Every bounded context should have its own persistence. However, you seem to manifest a lot of interest to the repositories. The most important part is identifying the bounded contexts and not the repositories.

Comment: I guess a generic repository would be suitable here as there is no domain logic.

Comment: That's up to you. Try with a generic one then refactor to a specific one if you need. Try the simples thing that works first.

Comment: Thanks.  I am almost ready to mark your answer.  What would you do with admin view models? For example, say I had a Production view model in the Production area and a Sales view model in the Sales area.  Would you create duplicate view models specifically for admin?

Comment: @w0051977 That's not a real DDD concern, but a UI concern. I suppose that if the admin needs a lot of additional features then yes.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you take a look at my other DDD type question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/356748/moving-role-crud-operations-from-the-controller-to-the-application-service ?

Comment: I see that you have answered quite a lot of CQRS questions.  Could you take a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46296030/why-is-getbyid-a-command-rather-than-a-query

Comment: @w0051977 I see that you already have a lot of answers and good folks that knows things. If you still have question after they respond to you then ask me again.

Comment: the other question was inspired by this one.  I am trying to understand whether I am following CQRS by having a read only administration facility.