# Moving Role CRUD operations from the Controller to the Application Service

Tags: c#, mvc, domain-driven-design, entity-framework

I am creating an administration facility for an asp.net MVC application.  I am currently trying to create a form that will allow admin users to create roles.  I see plenty of code, which looks like this online:

```
public class RoleController {

 ApplicationDbContext context;

        public RoleController()
        {
            context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Roles = context.Roles.ToList();
            return View(Roles);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var Role = new IdentityRole();
            return View(Role);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(IdentityRole Role)
        {
            context.Roles.Add(Role);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
 }
```

should I be putting code that connects to the database in the application service layer to be consistent or is there a reason not to do this?

Comment: Is this a c# specific question?

Comment: @Constantin Galbenu, yes the code is written in C#.  However, I guess it applies to any language, which uses ASP.NET Identity i.e. VB.NET as well.

Comment: In my php web applications I often use an application service in my presentation layer. I do like this, as opposed to injecting a database connection into http controllers, to call authorisation services and to have a well defined api.

Comment: So, all that my apllication can do is in the `api` namespace and is protected by an authorisation layer and/or logging and/or cache and so on.

Comment: @Constantin Galbenu, do you also have a service layer in a separate project?

Comment: No, no separate project. So, I have the following layers, in the same project: Presentation, Application, Infrastructure and Domain